# How Many Ohms is an Average Incandescent Lightbulb?

Tags: resistance, incandescent

The title says it all...

How many Ohms is an average incandescent lightbulb?

**EDIT**

After a few people making me realise that my question is kind of imprecise, here is what the question really asks:
If I enter a Walmart or a HomeDepot and I take a look at the incandescent lightbulbs section, what is the average resistance for all these lightbulbs (North America)?

Excuse me for the lack of precision.

Cheers.

Comment: OK, this is really impossible to answer. What's an "average" incandescent lightbulb, even? Back when they were common, devices had indicator bulbs (probably these contributed pretty heavily to the worldwide number of bulbs), and stadiums where also lit with incandescent bulbs; as you can imagine, a little light that tells you your car is running out of gas has different properties than a stadium floodlight. Also, come on, this is really, basic basic basic application of laws of electricity and you're not even showing any attempt. Do your homework!

Comment: Depends on whether it is on or off as well.

Comment: Use Ohms law to work back from the Wattage and the Voltage. Also note the actual filament resistance is different between when it is cold and when it is hot.

Comment: After calculating the hot resistance, you can estimate the cold resistance to be in the range of 1/9th of the hot resistance.

Comment: Any one lightbulb may vary over a 10:1 range between cold and hot, just to add to the total imprecision of the 'average' lightbulb. Average 240 V bulbs will have a much higher resistance than average 3 V bulbs.

Comment: After your edit, the question is still impossibly vague, and all the existing comments and answer still apply.

Answer (score 2):

Take 120^2/(light bulb wattage)=ohms of light bulb (or if using a 220V light bulb then use 220V)

This only works if the light bulb is on as the resistance changes when the filament heats up.

Comment: Re, "only works if the light bulb is on..." Your relationship of _instantaneous_ Wattage to instantaneous resistance is always valid (or, would be if all light bulbs were rated for 120V). Yeah, the resistance changes as the filament heats up, but don't forget that the actual Watts used changes as the resistance changes.

Comment: @Voltage Spike 120 *is* the RMS value.

Comment: Ha, I thought it was the peak to peak which is totally wrong, I didn't get enough sleep last night. That error is egregious